# Error when using EquationTrekker

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

I just got to know `EquationTrakker` because I need to do phase graphs for my classes.

When I load it

```
<< EquationTrekker`
```

everything works fine with no errors.

However when I try to use an example of the documentation, I get:

```
EquationTrekker[y''[x] + y[x] == 0, y, {x, π/8, 2 π}]
```

> During evaluation of In[7]:= LinkObject::linkd: Unable to communicate with closed link LinkObject['/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0/SystemFiles/Java/Linux-x86-64/bin/java' -classpath "/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0/SystemFiles… r -Djava.util.prefs.PreferencesFactory=com.wolfram.jlink.DisabledPreferencesFactory com.wolfram.jlink.Install -init "/tmp/m000004140851",480,4]. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[7]:= GUIRunModal::nvalid: The GUI definition contains invalid content. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[7]:= LinkObject::linkn: Argument LinkObject['/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0/SystemFiles/Java/Linux-x86-64/bin/java' -classpath "/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0/SystemFiles… r -Djava.util.prefs.PreferencesFactory=com.wolfram.jlink.DisabledPreferencesFactory com.wolfram.jlink.Install -init "/tmp/m000004140851",480,4] in LinkWrite[LinkObject['/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0/SystemFiles/Java/Linux-x86-64/bin/java' -classpath "/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0/Syst… a.util.prefs.PreferencesFactory=com.wolfram.jlink.DisabledPreferencesFactory com.wolfram.jlink.Install -init "/tmp/m000004140851",480,4],<<1>>] has an invalid LinkObject number; the link may be closed. >>
>
> ```
> $Failed
> ```

How can I fix this?

edit: forgot to mention I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. Haven't tried it on Windows 8 (dual boot)

edit2: It works properly on Windows 8. It looks like it's a problem with any java package in ubuntu...

Comment: Same - M10 on Fedora 20.

Comment: Works fine on v8 Fedora 20.

Comment: works on macos Mathematica 10.0

Comment: on version 10, windows 7, it hanged. But I saw message  `Message text not found -- (PropertyValue[{canvas ,canvasPane ,All},Name->trekPane ]) (1) >>` show up before it hanged

Answer (score 1):

On May 14 2019 submitted trouble ticket case number 4259890 because I could not get equation Trekker to work. I Received the following response from Duncan Pettengill."It does appear that equation Trekker is not behaving properly in mathematica version 11 and beyond.I have forwarded an issue report to the developers with your information"

Never heard another thing, still does not work. Would be nice to know if they have stopped supporting this. Thanks Larry Williams